# Check if gettext language is available

Tags: php, localization, gettext

After having some recent issues with `gettext`, I've got a couple of questions regarding how it works, and how I can avoid these issues in the future.
My issue was that I was trying to set the locale to `de`, rather than `de_DE`, which was not available on the server. My local copy was using the `php-gettext` package (is package the right term?), and so was happy using a locale that wasn't on the system. This has spawned 2 questions:

1. Why does the locale code `de_DE` work, when the directory structure is `locales/de/LC_MESSAGES/file.po`
2. How can I check that a locale is installed? e.g. If I want to use `de_DE.utf8`, but that's not available so I must fallback to `de_DE`, or `zh_HK` is unavailable so I want to fallback to `zh_CN`. I know these are edge cases, but I'd like to make the code as robust as possible. To clarify, this is if the locale is available on the system (as shown using the `locale -a` command), not if the file is available in the system.

Also, what's best practice for making this work on multiple platforms? My current code is:

```
$localeCode = 'de_DE'; // Example, would be generated
putenv('LANG=' . $localeCode);
putenv('LANGUAGE=' . $localeCode);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $localeCode);

$domain = 'mydomain'; // Again, example
// Don't load the locale from the cache
bindtextdomain($domain, '../locales/nocache');
bindtextdomain($domain, '../locales');
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

textdomain($domain);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Why does the locale code de_DE work, when the directory structure is
>      locales/de/LC_MESSAGES/file.po

I think it is a fallback. I am initializing my gettext by this:

```
$localeCode = 'en_US.utf8';       //<----
putenv('LANG=' . $localeCode);
putenv('LANGUAGE=' . $localeCode);
```

But I only have en_US directory and it works perfectly.

> 1. How can I check that a locale is installed? e.g. If I want to use
>      de_DE.utf8, but that's not available so I must fallback to de_DE, or
>      zh_HK is unavailable so I want to fallback to zh_CN. I know these are
>      edge cases, but I'd like to make the code as robust as possible. To
>      clarify, this is if the locale is available on the system (as shown
>      using the locale -a command), not if the file is available in the
>      system.

I think they are not edge cases. On linux systems you can list all locales by executing `locale -a` I think there are no function for this in php, but I found this solution for you:

```
$locale_data = array();

//Get locales from Linux terminal command locale
$locales = shell_exec('locale -a');

$locales = explode("n" , $locales);

foreach($locales as $c => $l)
{
    if(strlen($l))
    {
        $parts = explode('.' , $l);
        $lc = $parts[0];

        list($lcode , $ccode) = explode('_' , $lc);

        $lcode = strtolower($lcode);

        $language = $language_codes[$lcode];
        $country = $country_codes[$ccode];

        if(strlen($language) and strlen($country))
        {
            $locale_data[$l] = "$language - $country - {$parts[1]}";
        }
    }
}

print_r($locale_data);
```

For more information you should visit this page: http://www.binarytides.com/php-get-list-of-locales-installed-on-system/